# MVC Routing (attribute routing) and project structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routing

how would i organize my project structure, areas or folders to 
support logical grouping structure within my project.

www.mysite.com/org/{dynamic}/Importer/{controller}/{action}

Currently i have two areas

1. Org
2. Importer

Currently i have designed my site to work like this;

- www.mysite.com/Importer{area}/Controller/action
- www.mysite.com/Org{area}/Controller/action

I want to move "Importer" as a sub of area "Org" with a dynamic after "Org".

Making the routing work is one.

moving things create new obstacles like finding of the relative "View".

What would be a good way of setting up the structure to support this.

**Update**

```
 [RouteArea("Importer", AreaPrefix = "")]
    public class ViewImportFileController : BaseController
    {
        [Route("org/{orgName}/{area}/ViewImportFile")]
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
```

This is making it work, but does anyone else have experience with this type of thing and would like to know what they did.

**Update**

below you can see a snip bit of what it currently looks like.
This is existing code, and originally didn't set it up to work how i want it now.

what im wondering is does it make sense, to move all the code out of the Area (Importer) and move to default project structure, im thinking this doesnt really make sense either way.

[image]
it gets quite involved and tricky to work out what make more sense.
Areas are either making it more complicated or less, which is hard to determine given not many examples or write ups on setups like this.

The contractual routing - doesnt work as the routing is confusing
also the fact that this is in an area, i dont know.. even if you do this in the default register, the content is still under Importer... so..?

```cs
context.MapRoute(
    "Importer_default",
    "Org/{orgName}/Importer/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new[] { "Paradox.Web.Areas.Importer.Controllers" } //need for when using areas
);
```

given convetual what and that its in an area called Importer what would make this work...

```
http://mysite.com/Org/BoB-co/Importer/Source
http://mysite.com/Org/BoB-co/Importer/Source/Create
http://mysite.com/Org/BoB-co/Importer/Source/Edit/3
http://mysite.com/Org/BoB-co/Importer/Source/Delete/3

http://mysite.com/Org/BoB-co/Importer/FileSpecifcation/4

http://mysite.com/Org/Bob-co/Importer/Template/3
http://mysite.com/Org/Bob-co/Importer/Template/Create/3

http://mysite.com/Org/Bob-co/Importer/ViewImportFile
```

I have managed to get close but using attribute routing which looks ok, im just trying to keep things simple**

currently while trying with attributes like below
.. this makes the link look like

http://mysite.com/Org/Bob-co/Importer/Source/Template/TransformationSystemSpecs/Index/4

instead of

http://mysite.com/Org/Bob-co/Importer/Source/Template/TransformationSystemSpecs/4

which i can make work by un-commenting

// [Route("{id}")]

what im trying to achieve is setting up things so they work by convention rather than me having to specify things

```cs
[RouteArea("Importer", AreaPrefix = "")]
[RoutePrefix("Org/{orgName}/Importer/Source/Template/FileSpecifcation")]
[OrgName]
[Route("{action=Index}/{id?}")]//Without this, you need to define "[Route]" above every Action-Method
public class FileSpecifcationController : BaseController
{
   // [Route("{id}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(int? id)
    {
    }

   // [Route("_ExcelSheetDataSave")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult _ExcelSheetDataSave(int templateId, string sheetName, string tempFilename, string orginalFilename)
    {  
    }

    [HttpPost]
  //  [Route("_ChangeExcelSheetNameSave")]
    public ActionResult _ChangeExcelSheetNameSave(ExcelChangeSheetName model)
    {  
    }
 }
```

Comment: how does this get marked down this is software engineering right not SO. 
im asking about advanced routing aka pretty urls, and how they should be structured in a project which has sub structure.

Comment: something like this https://exceptionnotfound.net/attribute-routing-vs-convention-routing/ but with how to organize the controller and views

Comment: I think that part of the challenge is your question is sufficiently vague that it's difficult to provide meaningful perspective to your question.  And where you're asking about project structure, it looks like you're really asking about routing structure.  This appears to be more a question of REST API than MVC layout.  I suspect you're using MS's ASP.NET MVC which does not use MVC terminology in the traditional sense.

Comment: @GlenH7 thanks for the response, my q is beyond all the defaults so to speak, its about Routing...mainly (attribute routing) and mvc but there isnt a route category, its not really about api, its more about how mvc picks up controllers and views. Hence the q become more about structure. its hard when you dont know the terminology to google in this instance as its not something common, this is like once you go beyond the norms. aka i have two areas... now want to make one a sub of the other with a dynamic.. i need someone who has done this before who can give, there findings.. as restructuring

Comment: is a lot of work, which i don't want to have to do, then un-do, then re-do while trying to find something which fits.

Comment: its almost like my q is too *advance* or non common that ppl who come across dont understand, but instead trying to understand they assume i dont know what im doing lol. tricky i tell you, when you trying to find experience in something and ppl just dismiss as they haven't gone to this level. q - how should i structure my project given that currently i have two areas, then end goal is 1 is a sub of the other with a dynamic in-between.  as per the original q. my be im asking on the wrong place i thought this is what SE was for?

Comment: I have changed the tags for you so it's more clear to others what you're asking.  Try providing some concrete examples that are causing concern.  Be specific.  "I think foo and bar belong together at this point, but bar and baz overlap at this other point.  I think that to efficiently program this, I should ... but I'm worried about ... "  Where you fill in for foo, bar, baz, and the blanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, your Questions are valid.
Unfortunately, not many developers here understand how to properly implement Areas and Routing, so they downvote what they don't understand.

The problem with your question is you open by asking a Software Engineering/Architecture question about how to properly structure your project, then you immediately go into asking a different (StackOverflow appropriate) question on how to shoehorn in one Area under another.
Which is it?
Do you want to learn how to do this right in a general sense, or do you want to push this square-peg into a round-hole for a specific problem you're facing?
I think that's what frustrated the down-voters.

I haven't had experience with what you are doing.
I don't know if it's a "*code-smell*", but I would avoid adding Variables before my `AreaName`.
However, I *do* understand you want your `Importer` URL's to appear just like they would in your `Org` Area.

What I've learned is that you **cannot** mix *both* Routing-Attributes and `context.MapRoute()`.
Because of this, I **removed** all of my Routing-Attributes,
     because I prefer the programmatic control in C# for writing my Routes.
An example of a Routing-Attribute is your: `[RouteArea("Importer", AreaPrefix = "")]`

Below is an example of how you may be able to do this in your `AreaRegistraion` File.
Please keep in mind, I quickly wrote this to try and fit your scenario *without* any testing.
You will have to iron out the details to make it work for you.

FYI: I noticed you were **Mixing Case** in your answer.
Note: Case-Sensitivity in your Routes **matter** for MVC to Map to your Areas (and Parameters too, I think).

```
public class ImporterAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
{
    public override string AreaName { get { return "Importer"; } }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        string Default_ControllerName = "ViewImportFile";
        string Default_ActionName     = "Index";

        //Area Default:
        context.MapRoute(//Note: URL Routes are Case-Sensitive, so "org" will not map to "Org".
            "Org" + "_" +  "OrgName"  + "_" + AreaName,//Name.
            "Org" + "/" + "{OrgName}" + "/" + AreaName,//URL.
            new { controller = Default_ControllerName, action = Default_ActionName }//Defaults.
        );

        //Controller Default(s):
        context.MapRoute(
             ("Org" + "_" +  "OrgName"  + "_" + AreaName + "_" + Default_ControllerName),//Name.
             ("Org" + "/" + "{OrgName}" + "/" + AreaName + "/" + Default_ControllerName),//URL.
            new { controller = Default_ControllerName, action = Default_ActionName }//Defaults.
        );

        //Optional: List other Controllers (besides the Default_ControllerName) that will also have
        //          Default Actions to Map to (when missing in the URL). - 07/07/2019 - MCR.
        //context.MapRoute(
        //     ("Org" + "/" + "{OrgName}" + "/" + AreaName + "_" + "ControllerName"),//Name.
        //     ("Org" + "/" + "{OrgName}" + "/" + AreaName + "/" + "ControllerName"),//URL.
        //    new { controller = "ControllerName", action = "ActionName" }//Defaults.
        //);

        //Catch-All:
        context.MapRoute(
            ("Org" + "_" +  "OrgName"  + "_" + AreaName + "_" + "Default"),//Name.
            ("Org" + "/" + "{OrgName}" + "/" + AreaName + "/{controller}/{action}")//URL.
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, see update, to get a better idea of what im working with... the above did not seem to work.